# Running the unit test for zxing fails

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant, compiler-errors, zxing

I'm trying to run the unit tests for [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/). I'm running

```
ant test-blackbox
```

This fails, however, with the output:

```
Buildfile: c:\Workspace\zxing-2.1\core\build.xml

init:

build:

build-test:
    [javac] Compiling 109 source files to c:\Workspace\zxing-2.1\core\build-test
    [javac] c:\Workspace\zxing-2.1\core\test\src\com\google\zxing\client\result\URIParsedResultTestCase.java:73: error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
    [javac]                  "\u0013\u0013Â¬Ã¦Z{âˆšÏ€âˆšÃ©âˆšÃ¹âˆšÃ¶Â¬Ã³ZÂ¬ÃŸÂ¬Â®+y_zbâˆšÂ±k\u00117Â¬âˆ?\u000EÂ¬ÃœâˆšÃº\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000" +
    [javac]                                                                                            ^
    [javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
c:\Workspace\zxing-2.1\core\build.xml:54: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: I added that to my question, see my edit.

Comment: Nevermind, the error wasn't in the build.xml, but in the encoding used by the java compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the error was because the files are encoded using UTF-8, but the compiler uses Windows default encoding. I fixed the error by defining a new environment variable - `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`, and setting it to `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`, as outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/623036/492336

Answer (score 1):

Forget about generating core.jar yourself it is a big headache

Just download latest library from:https://github.com/zxing/zxing

and download readymade jar of any version you want from here: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/

That's all.